# Thumbnail preview appears and immediately disappears

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, thumbnails

I have a problem with the thumbnails of picture files. When I open a OneDrive folder, the Thumbnail preview appears and immediately disappears. It flashes when I scroll down in the folder but as soon as I stop scrolling the thumbnails disappears and the filetype placeholder image is shown again.

this affects all pictures/videos stored in (and only in) OneDrive. As soon as I copy a picture folder from OneDrive to my desktop, the thumbnails in the copied folder work fine.

What I have tried so far (i followed [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10)):

- recreating thumbnails cache using cleanmgr.exe
- deleting the thumbnails cache via command line (del /f /s /q /a %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db)
- gpedit.msc > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Component > File Explorer > Turn Off Caching of Thumbnail Pictures = Enabled

My System:

- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.267)
- Lenovo ThinkPad E590
- OneDrive Client Version: 19.123.0624.0002
- Latest patch level for everything (windows, drivers and applications)

**Question**:
What else can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem in the past month.  I've found that it only happens when OneDrive isn't syncing files (perhaps because your computer is on battery-saver mode so OneDrive pauses syncing, or somehow OneDrive isn't signed in properly).  This issue seems to happen when OneDrive can't contact its server.

It worked for me once I ensured that OneDrive is properly signed in and synced.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem twice.

First about 2 months ago, when I tried EVERYTHING there was to be found about it, but with no result.

However, the thumbnails luckily just started appearing by themselves again after about 4 weeks.

But then it happened again today, and I tried all the available suggested resolutions, but again, NOTHING worked. I even deleted OneDrive just in case but that didn't help either.

Then, after about 8 hours of frustration I just tried a crazy idea of my own - just as the first time this happened, the photos on any USB-drive I connected were shown correctly, so I copied a pictures-folder on my computer to the USB, deleted the folder on my computer, emptied the trash bin, and then copied the folder back to the computer - and there they were, shown correctly!

I have then copied several folders of pictures (1000+) back and forth to/from the USB-drive in one operation and they are all showing correctly now, also after restart and removal of the USB.

Obviously it can all be done in one single operation - just copy 'Pictures' to an external Hard Drive or USB, delete them from the computer, copy them back and there they are, thumbnails and all! So ridiculously simple, and it WORKS!